# Bootstrap typeahead returning displayed value instead of id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap, with a javascript "borrowed" from https://gist.github.com/dinnouti/3896201

```
$ ->
  $('select[rel="autocomplete"]').each ->
    option = []     
    $(this).find('option').each ->     
      option.push $(this).text()

    input = $('<input>')
    input.attr('type','text')
    input.attr('name', $(this).attr('name') )
    input.attr('id', $(this).attr('id') )  
    input.attr('class', $(this).attr('class') )
    input.attr('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder') )
    input.attr('data-provide', 'typeahead' )
    input.val($(this).attr('data_default'))
    $(this).replaceWith(input)

    $(input).typeahead({
      source : option
      updater: (item) ->
        @$element[0].value = item
        @$element[0].form.submit()
        item
    });
```

In my view I have

```
= form_tag home_select_path, autocomplete: 'off' do
  = select_tag 'subject', options_for_select(get_subjects), class: 'select optional', include_blank: false, rel: 'autocomplete'
```

This works fine, but, returns the value being displayed to my controller, so that I have to do a "reverse find" to find back the object ID referred to...

Is there a way I can change this to return the object's ID instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself. I added a "map" to my javascript, storing the "text/value" pairs from the select options as a javascript hash. I now use that hash to lookup the item's id in the updater, and assign that as value to the input field. It is this value that is apparently sent to the controller...

```
$ ->
  $('select[rel="autocomplete"]').each ->
    option = []
    map = {}
    $(this).find('option').each ->     
      option.push $(this).text()
      map[$(this).text()] = $(this).attr('value')

    ...

    $(input).typeahead({
      updater: (item) ->
        @$element[0].value = map[item]
        @$element[0].form.submit()
        item
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that "get_subjects" contains a list that has **id** and **name** attributes
so when the form is submitted it will get the ID value instead of the name of the select_tag

you could try changing

```
options_for_select(get_subjects)
```

to

```
options_from_collection_for_select(get_subjects,"id","name")
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. If I debug the controller, it is still the name that comes in in the params hash. No id...

Comment: can you post ung implementation of get_subjects? maybe that's where the problem is occurring.

Comment: for the moment get_subjects is simple Subject.all, so no chance there. I suspect the javascript part, but I'm no specialist in that